# Initialize variable in Scala Object through some method (similar to init method in class)

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I want to implement init method kind of functionality in my object. for ex , my object structure is as follows:

```
object MyObject {
  var set: Set[String] = _
  var map : Map[String, String] =_
  var list: List[Integer] =_ 
  init()  

  def init() {
    // read external file and initialze variables
    set = ..
    map = ..
    list = .. 
  }
}
```

I have defined a init method and called init method from object itself. 
Is this a correct way to do it or can i achieve the same functionality through any better way?

Answer (score 4):

You definitely don't want to have those things as `var`s, but the good news is you don't have to.  How about something like this:

```
object MyObject {

  private[this] val data: List[String] = {
    // pretend we are reading this from a file
    List("1","2","3")
  }

  val set: Set[String] = data.toSet
  val map: Map[String, String] = data.map(x => (x,x)).toMap
  val list: List[Int] = data.map(_.toInt)
}
```

If you like having the `init()` function, you can do something like this (though it's a bit clunkier):

```
object MyObject {

  private[this] def init() = {
    val data: List[String] = {
      // pretend we are reading this from a file
      List("1","2","3")
    }

    val set = data.toSet
    val map = data.map(x => (x,x)).toMap
    val list = data.map(_.toInt)

    (set, map, list)        
  }

  val (
    set: Set[String],
    map: Map[String, String],
    list: List[Int]) 
      = init()
}
```

Comment: In your second example, you could drop the type declaration from the tuple unpacking for `val (set, map, list)`, but perhaps that would make the field a bit ambiguous as for what it's type actually is

Comment: @Yuval, True. (And they're not required in the first example either.) I was just trying to keep the syntax as close to the original as possible.

Comment: In the first example ,all the variables  set, map and list have been initialized from the List "data" . This might not be my case . My question was more of a use case , where we have to read a xml file and create mutiple datastructure out of it. For ex: i might have multiple maps as well for different use case. But i guess, your 2nd example would fit all the scenarios

Comment: @Alok, In the first case, the declaration body of the object is basically just a function so you can do anything you want in it; a nested `init()` function is entirely superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

## General explanation

In Scala the `body` of the object `is` the `init`-Method.

So this is completely equivalent to the version you described above.

```
object MyObject {
  private[this] val data: List[String] = {List("1","2","3")}

  var mySet: Set[String] = data.toSet
  var myMap: Map[String, String] = data.map(x => (x,x)).toMap
  var list: List[Int] = data.map(_.toInt)
}
```

and please do not redefine `map` this will lead to a lot of pain.

## Example with external resource:

### conf file `conf.xml`

```
<config>
  <size>42</size>
</config>
```

### scala object `Example.scala`

```
object Example {
  var size : Int =  (XML.loadFile("conf.xml") \\ "size").text.toInt

  println("I am initialized on object creation: >" + size + "<")
}
```

### usage in REPL

```
scala> :load Example.scala
Loading Example.scala...

import scala.xml.XML
defined object Example

scala> Example
I am initialized on object creation: >42<
res0: Example.type = Example$@3c73951
```

Comment: This wouldnt serve my purpose . I need a method , to initialize all the variables, since i need to parse a xml file to initialize these var, which would be possible in a method only. Also there could be multiple map which i might have to initialize

Comment: I will extend the example to show you how you can do this.